# Can Microsoft Detours be used to hook system-wide calls without injecting into every proc?

Tags: windows, winapi, detours

I want to hook *every* call to `CreateProcess` (and a few other related APIs), no matter the process. Can modern Detours be used to do this without enumerating all processes and performing injections?

I've read several articles on both API hooking and doing so specifically with Detours, re:

[API Hooking with MS Detours](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours)

[API Hooking with MS Detours (InfoSec Institute)](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/api-hooking-detours/#gref)

[API Hooking Revealed](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed)

I have two problems with these articles:

1. They are quite old and things may have changed.
2. They do not thoroughly address system-wide hooking using Detours specifically.

I am aware that this can be done with a driver, but Detours is said to be a powerful tool, and is still currently supported, so I wanted to know how it could be done with Detours.

The literature I've read thus far is geared toward targeting a specific program using Detours, and although it has presented an idea of how it's possible to enumerate every process and perform a DLL injection and then try to use Detours, this seems like a very unreliable way.

Comment: Do you understand how a detour works? Do you really expect a process that you don't inject into to be detoured?

Comment: Yes I do but I'm finding it hard to believe that this could be a feasible method of hooking widespread calls like this, for example for anti virus or and hack software. Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: You think that some random process is just going to start sending you messages without you asking for it. If you actually think about what a detour is, you can answer your own question.

Comment: @the_endian: antiviruses, firewalls, etc operate at a much lower level than user-level apps normally run at. They use customized system drivers, low level system hooks and callbacks, etc. Hooking `CreateProcess` is a higher level approach to a lower level issue. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Does Detours not use any drivers/ low-level callbacks to work its magic even when it comes to handling the in-memory stuff?

Comment: @the_endian no, it does not. It is just patching functions directly in memory. So it doesn't work across process boundaries. Read the [technical paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/detours-binary-interception-of-win32-functions/) that explains how Detours actually does its work

Comment: No it does not. It is well documented what a detour is. I wonder whether you really understand it yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no I got it I read the paper on the detours site that explains the trampoline and everything. It's just one of the articles states that detours comes with a "toolset for system-wide detours" so I wasn't sure if there was something else going on besides the blatantly obvious. Apparently not. Or the article which said that was poorly worded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### NO

Detours cannot be used globally without per-process injection.

However, you only need to enumerate processes manually once, when you want to set an initial hook after the system is already running. One option (if you are careful with it) is to use the [`AppInit_DLLs` Registry setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197571/working-with-the-appinit-dlls-registry-value) to have your DLL loaded into new processes (well, at least processes that use `user32.dll`, and that don't opt-out of letting `AppInit_DLLs` run, and providing that [`AppInit_DLLs` is even enabled on the system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280412.aspx) to begin with).

Otherwise, the alternative is to write a kernel driver that implements a [process creation callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt764085.aspx) that is registered via [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951.aspx).  That callback will be called every time a process is created or destroyed.

Comment: [AppInit_DLLs should be renamed Deadlock_Or_Crash_Randomly_DLLs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071213-00/?p=24183).

Comment: In 2017 `AppInit_Dlls` doesn't more often than it does. See: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16329/3939 Also, the claim that it injects into "*every* new process was *always* wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable: Raymond's argument is pretty weak there. The [guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx) that says to not call `LoadLibrary` from `DllMain` is similar to the guideline that says not to call `CreateThread` from `DllMain`. It's fine in and of itself. The problem starts when you make assumptions that weren't guaranteed (e.g. that the DLL is initialized when `LoadLibrary` returns) or take *extra* steps (*wait* on the thread you created).

Comment: If you know what you're doing, both are fine. The guidelines are for people who don't know, and for them MSDN takes a buffer zone for safety by being more restrictive that actually necessary.